# Google Fonts German GDPR IP Address

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I (or a lot of German people) need your help.

In Germany, more and more website operators are receiving a legal letter with a warning and are supposed to pay around €170. The problem is that it doesn't stop there, which means that if you pay the €170, someone else can come right away and warn you again.

It's about Google Fonts. Many Wordpress websites use themes that load Google Fonts. The German court has decided that it is not allowed to send the IP address to the Google because of Google Fonts and this is a violation of the rights of the customers.

Since I run a few websites, I'm now looking for a solution, but to be honest I'm coming up against technical limits. So I want to open this thread to discuss possibilities.

I have listed issues below, I will add them to my solutions.

I can think of the following options:

1. Create a child theme and then load the Google fonts locally. (Issue: 1st 2nd 3rd 4th)
2. Service worker that rewrites the URLs
   (Issue: 5.)
3. Nginx rewrite, rewrite the php output and replace google fonts url
   (Issuing: 1. 4.)

More?

Issues:

1. If you have e.g. integrated a script (Google Maps, Recaptcha, Intercom, ...) it can happen that Google Fonts are reloaded by Javascript.
2. Theme updates.
3. A lot of work when multiple customers.
4. Plugins load elements on certain pages or only later after it can happen that google fonts are loaded again.
5. Only works if the service worker is installed

I am open for any idea. It looks like Google will not fix this.

Comment: Simple, don't use Google fonts at all. I loathe that sites now load them from the internet. There is zero reason to. Choose Arial, then let the user decide if they want to change it.

Comment: This is not how it works.

Comment: What do you means `This is not how it works`! Do not code in the request, If you have thirdparty code which references it, then either modify it or don't use it. Reject Google fonts.

Comment: "Don't use it" - What if there is no other alternative or the customer insists on using a google font?

Comment: Yes or like i wrote you have Intercom or whatever and all the Wordpress Themes using Google Fonts.

Comment: Ask the user to agree to send your data to Google, if the user don't agree don't let him use your service. We do so

Comment: This is a good idea. But then i need to do it with nginx or something similar. Because if the normal page will start to load it will fetch it with <link href 

Do you have a sample?

Comment: How exactly do you thinks things worked before Google decided to take over web fonts?

Comment: @Bib for sure i can prevent using Google Fonts. But it is the same like when i say i have a car with petrol but i should not use petrol anymore.

Comment: @DarkBee I'm not sure I know of an OS that doesn't include a font of its own. There is always an alternative: the fonts already on the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy technical fix. The only long-term fix is to review how you include any third-party content on your websites, in case this embedding causes any visitor personal data to flow to such third parties.

This is not a new development. A lot of the relevant compliance steps already entered the (German) mainstream in the early 2010s when the problem was Facebook's “Like button”. The generally accepted solution for that is that the third party content is not loaded directly. Instead, a placeholder widget is rendered that indicates which content would be available there. Then, the user can give consent with one click and the actual embedded content is loaded.

With Google Fonts, no such consent flow is needed or appropriate. All of the fonts on Google Fonts are Open Source licensed – you are allowed to use and distribute them for free, but subject to the license conditions (like making the license notice available to users). So on a technical level, it is easy to self-host the fonts in question.

What is tricky is efficiently rewriting the requests caused by your websites to point to your own servers instead of to the Google servers. You have identified a couple of approaches and have identified their pros and cons. Some comments:

- Client-side rewriting sounds very fragile, I'd avoid it.
- Server-side rewriting can be very powerful, but would also be somewhat fragile. The main advantage of such rewrites would be that it doesn't just handle Google Fonts embeds from your themes, but also requests inserted by server-side plugins.
- Updating the theme is the only reliable long-term solution. Creating a child theme might be a suitable stop-gap measure until the theme developer fixes the problem. Similarly, it may be necessary to temporarily modify WordPress plugins.

I think that as a band-aid, server-side rewrites will be good enough to prevent many automated scanning tools used by these cease-and-desist lawyers from sounding the alarm on your sites.

However, you have correctly identified that especially JavaScript could cause problems for achieving actual compliance. This is why you should revisit your decisions about what plugins and scripts you have integrated. Loading third party JavaScript has pretty much the same legal consequences as loading fonts from Google, so you should only do it if it's actually necessary for your site (where necessity depends on the *user's* perspective), or if the user has given valid consent. For example, you can use the placeholder widget technique mentioned above for embedded content like Google Maps or Intercom, whereas loading a Captcha may indeed be strictly necessary on some pages.

For testing these issues, I'd recommend installing Firefox with the uBlock Origin addon, and setting the addon to [hard mode](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Blocking-mode:-hard-mode). This will block all third-party/cross-origin requests. You can then allowlist those domains that are under your direct control, or are provided by your data processors (who are contractually bound to only use the personal data as instructed by you, and are considered first-party for GDPR purposes), or domains for which you have a legal basis to share the data (e.g. a “legitimate interest” to load stuff that is strictly necessary for your site to work, or to investigate what requests are made when the user gives consent).

Comment: you summed it up perfectly. Thanks a lot for this. For the future and the messy internet, it would be great if there were a new browser API that would make things easier to control. That you block cross side domains first and then release them.

Comment: @DanielEhrhardt [CSP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) already give the server a good degree of control here. For example, you can limit `font-src 'self'`. For managing user consent dynamically, most sites integrate some third party cookie consent framework – browser vendors don't want to be involved with such aspects that carry so much liability.

Answer (score 0):

**IANAL** but the two sections may be relevant.

- [Using their APIs](https://developers.google.com/terms#section_2_using_our_apis).  From what I can tell nothing here explicitly forbids proxying.
- [API Prohibitions on sublicensing](https://developers.google.com/terms#a_api_prohibitions).  The last part of the statement *and offer it for use by third parties* means you're okay as long as you're not offering it for other people to use.

I do have [Google Fonts Proxy Docker Image](https://github.com/trajano/google-fonts-proxy-docker) which I use for my own stacks, I don't offer the use of my **running proxy** for use with other services.  It does not mean you can't simply deploy my image on your own servers.

This won't resolve your 3rd party Google services such as Maps though.